# use ajax object value as string stored in php variable for IF statement

Tags: php, ajax, if-statement

I have radio group selects a user can choose from that get sent to my php file through ajax, (only the selected option from each group gets their value passed). I can $_POST() grab those values, save them in php variables and print_r() those variables successfully as so:

print_r() result ex: (in browser page)

```
Array ( [0] => Customer ) Array ( [0] => Completed Workorders ) Array ( [0] => All Workorders )
```

I am also able to use two of my other variables (from other checkbox values stored as an array) successfully in a MySQL WHERE clause.

Now, I'm trying to build a series of IF statements that say if the php variable = "[one of two value options from the radio group]" then $whereclause = "Some kind of value".

MY HTML CODE:

```
// first radio group: user must select one or the other.
<label for="revenueCustomer">Customer</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueTblType[]" id="revenueCustomer" value="Customer">

<label for="revenueCategory">Revenue Category</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueTblType[]" id="revenueCategory" value="Revenue Category">



// Second radio group: user must select one or the other.
<label for="revenueCompletedWO">Completed Workorders</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWO[]" id="revenueCompletedWO" value="Completed Workorders">

<label for="revenueStatusWO">Workorder Status</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWO[]" id="revenueStatusWO" value="Workorder Status">



// Third radio group: user must select one or the other.
<label for="revenueAllWO">All Workorders</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWODate[]" id="revenueAllWO" value="All Workorders">

<label for="revenueDateRangeWO">Workorder Date Range</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWODate[]" id="revenueDateRangeWO" value="Workorder Date Range">
```

My $_POST() CODE:

```
//Get Table Type.
if (isset($_POST['revenueTblType'])) {
  $revenueTblType = $_POST['revenueTblType'];
  print_r($revenueTblType);
};

//Get Report Type
if (isset($_POST['revenueWO'])) {
  $revenueWO = $_POST['revenueWO'];
  print_r($revenueWO);
};

//Get date include value.
if (isset($_POST['revenueWODate'])) {
  $revenueWODate = $_POST['revenueWODate'];
  print_r($revenueWODate);
};

//Get date range.
$revenuefromajax=$_POST['revenuefrom'];
$revenuetoajax=$_POST['revenueto'];

$revenuefromstring = strtotime($revenuefromajax);
$revenuetostring = strtotime($revenuetoajax);

$revenuefrom=date("Y-m-d", $revenuefromstring);
$revenueto=date("Y-m-d", $revenuetostring);

//Get selected Status Values.
if (isset($_POST['revenue_checkboxes'])) {
  $revenue_check = $_POST['revenue_checkboxes'];
};
```

My IF statements:

```
if ($revenueTblType == 'Customer') {
        $groupbyclause = "x.company";
        $columnheader = 'Customer';
        $columnname = 'company';
    }
    else if ($revenueTblType == 'Revenue Category') {
        $groupbyclause = "x.revenue";
        $columnheader = 'Revenue Category';
        $columnname = 'revenue';
    }
    else {
        $groupbyclause = "x.revenue";
        $columnheader = 'Revenue Category';
        $columnname = 'revenue';
    }


    if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'All Workorders')) {
        $whereclause = "x.stagestatus = 'Complete'";
    }
    else if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'Workorder Date Range')) {
        $whereclause = "(x.stagestatus = 'Complete') AND (x.shippeddate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."')"; 
    }
    else if ($revenueWO == 'Workorder Status') {
         $whereclause = "x.stagestatus IN (". implode(',', array_map(function($item) {return '"' . $item . '"'; }, $revenue_check)) .")";
    }
    else {
        $whereclause = "x.stagestatus = 'Complete'";
    }
```

When I run through this code, the result is always the "else" result even though the values for the selected buttons come through successfully.

Do I have to do something to the ajax results so I can use the sent values in my IF statements?

All help is welcome.

Thank you!!!

Comment: you only ever set `$revenuwWO` if that particular checkbox was set. That means ALL of your `if()` tests fail, because an undefined variable is always assumed to have a `null` value, and `null == 'anything'` is false. so the only valid execution path is through that final `else` clause.

Comment: the radio buttons the users can choose from are organized in three radio groups so one option for each group is always selected and sent through ajax to php. I can print_r() those values from my php page to the browser and successfully see the value. The if statement is supposed to choose a result if one radio is selected over the other. I'm just not sure why I can print the values stored in the php variable, but my if statement can't "see" the same variable's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a few simple edits, I was able to successfully execute my code. For those of you looking for help to a similar question, this is what worked for me:

Previously, I had my radio select group names as "revenueTblType[]", "revenueWO[]" and "revenueWODate[]". However, (silly me) radio select groups don't need the array distinction in the name like checkboxes do because only one value gets sent (since only one radio option in a group can be selected. By removing "[]" from each name, my ajax was able to bring over each value without being in an array and my if statement was able to test for the condition successfully.

Also, another change I had to make was removing the final "else" condition of each if statement. During testing, I would see my first table build based on the if condition. But, then my table would change once the program got to the else condition that I didn't need. After removing the extra code, my correct table displayed.

MY CODE:

HTML:

```
// first radio group: user must select one or the other.
<label for="revenueCustomer">Customer</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueTblType" id="revenueCustomer" value="Customer">

<label for="revenueCategory">Revenue Category</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueTblType" id="revenueCategory" value="Revenue Category">



// Second radio group: user must select one or the other.
<label for="revenueCompletedWO">Completed Workorders</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWO" id="revenueCompletedWO" value="Completed Workorders">

<label for="revenueStatusWO">Workorder Status</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWO" id="revenueStatusWO" value="Workorder Status">



// Third radio group: user must select one or the other.
<label for="revenueAllWO">All Workorders</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWODate" id="revenueAllWO" value="All Workorders">

<label for="revenueDateRangeWO">Workorder Date Range</label>
<input type="radio" name="revenueWODate" id="revenueDateRangeWO" value="Workorder Date Range">
```

IF Statements:

```
if ($revenueTblType == 'Customer') {
    $groupbyclause = "x.company";
    $columnheader = 'Customer';
    $columnname = 'company';
}
else if ($revenueTblType == 'Revenue Category') {
    $groupbyclause = "x.revenue";
    $columnheader = 'Revenue Category';
    $columnname = 'revenue';
}
/* Removed this section of code...
else {
    $groupbyclause = "x.revenue";
    $columnheader = 'Revenue Category';
    $columnname = 'revenue';
}
*/

if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'All Workorders')) {
    $whereclause = "x.stagestatus = 'Complete'";
}
else if (($revenueWO == 'Completed Workorders') and ($revenueWODate == 'Workorder Date Range')) {
    $whereclause = "(x.stagestatus = 'Complete') AND (x.shippeddate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."')"; 
}
else if ($revenueWO == 'Workorder Status') {
     $whereclause = "x.stagestatus IN (". implode(',', array_map(function($item) {return '"' . $item . '"'; }, $revenue_check)) .")";
}
/* Removed this section of code...
else {
    $whereclause = "x.stagestatus = 'Complete'";
}
*/
```

I hope this helps others too!

Thank you.